# Cannot Understand JUnit4 @BeforeClass and Static variables

Tags: junit4, static-members, fixtures

I have code like

```
private static Path file1;  // reference file

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass()
{
    Path file1 = Files.createTempFile(testFolder, "test-", ".txt");
}

@Test
public void testIdentical()
{
    assertNotNull(file1); // fails
}
```

But `file1` is null. I have been searching for answers to this problem, and while the issues are similar, no-one ever seams to explain clearly what exactly is going on, or how to do what I want to do: which is for `file1` to not be null.

I am doing what https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-fixtures seems to indicate is correct, but I am not getting the results I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning to a local variable here:

```
Path file1 = Files.createTempFile(testFolder, "test-", ".txt");
```

do this instead:

```
file1 = Files.createTempFile(testFolder, "test-", ".txt");
```

Comment: Doh! Darn copy/paste, and I was not paying attention. Now I feel like an idiot. Many thanks :-)

Comment: Happens sometimes to all, no worries.